# Best way to enforce substantial password change, without saving to plaintext?

Tags: hash, passwords

Trying to come up a cryptographically safe way to hash a user's password so that I'm able to tell if a new password user is picking is "significantly different" from the original one, without having to save the original password in clear text.  Is this something doable?

Answer (score 2):

You have the user enter their old password along with the new one (which you *should* be doing anyway). Compare the hash of the old to your stored hash of old for verification, then compare the two plaintext passwords provided: the old and the new.

Comment: and if there was 24 remembered passwords?

Comment: Honestly? Probably a bad idea to be doing it like that. Anyway, the correct (and only) way would be to store previous passwords as encrypted text and not hashed data in that case. But then you must be very, very careful with your encryption key.

Comment: A drawback is that the user can bypass the comparison through the "password recovery" workflow, where s/he does not need to enter the old password while setting a new password.

Answer (score 1):

No its not, that's the whole idea with hashing!

You would need to use reversible encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach:

- Ask the user to enter his old and his new passwords
- Check that the old password is correct
- Compare both plaintext passwords and check for similarity (using something like [fuzzy matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching))